# Extracting one object/group out of a JSON array and save it to a new file using PHP. I am hung up on the array part of the code

Tags: php, json

I have the following json structure I am trying to loop through and extract products from:

```
[]JSON
->{0}
-->[]username
-->[]avatar
-->[]rep
-->[]products
-->[]groups
-->[]feedbacks
-->[]online
-->[]staff
```

I am trying to ave only the products object into as a JSON file. This is the only result I need and delete/unset the rest:

```
[]JSON
->{0}
-->[]products
```

But I seem to be a bit confused, as I am not to familiar with how arrays work around PHP. Here is an angle I am currently trying:

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents('test.json');
$json_decoded = json_decode($str,true);
foreach($json_decoded as $index){
unset($json_decoded[$index][???]);
        }
file_put_contents('cleaned.json', json_encode($json_decoded));
?>
```

I added ??? where I am lost, this is about as far as I have gotten. I keep getting super confused. I know the structure will always be the same as above so I can technically just remove username,avatar,rep,groups,feedbacks,online, and staff seperatly. Which is just fine.

Here is an example of the json structure:

```
[{"username":["1"],"avatar":["yellow"],"rep":["etc"],"products":["Big"],"groups":["small"],"feedbacks":["small"],"online":["small"],"staff":["small"]}]
```

Thank you in advance, even a push in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: .assign it to a new variable. it's more efficient. you might need the other data later on.  `$product = $json_decoded->products`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compose a new products array like this :

```php
$products = [];

foreach($json_data as $value) {
    $products[]['products'] = $value['products'];
}

file_put_contents('cleaned.json', json_encode($products));
```

This will results json objects like this :

```
[
    {
        "products": ["Big-01"]
    },
    {
        "products": ["Big-02"]
    },
    {
        "products": ["Big-03"]
    },
    {
        "products": ["Big-04"]
    },
    {
        "products": ["Big-05"]
    }
]
```

Comment: I have checked your snippet & updated my answer to use array instead of object

Comment: Thanks a million, that was the problem. You are much appreciated for the help.

Answer (score 1):

From your snippet. try this.

```
<?php
$str = '[{"username":["1"],"avatar":["yellow"],"rep":["etc"],"products":["Big"],"groups":["small"],"feedbacks":["small"],"online":["small"],"staff":["small"]}]';
$json_decoded = json_decode($str,true);

foreach($json_decoded as $value) {
    $products = $value['products'];
}

print_r( $products);
?>
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Big
)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton man for all your help. You had the same approach with the array as explained in another answer. I can't thank you enough, I was pulling my hair out over this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array (`$products`), iterate over the old array, and set `products` as the one property instead of `unset`ing every single array.

```php
$products = [];
foreach ($json_decoded as $index) {
  $products[$index] = [
    'products' => $json_decoded[$index]['products']
  ];
}
file_put_contents('cleaned.json', json_encode($products));
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't even consider this, two of you have told me essentially the same solution now. I am having an issue with an empty cleaned.json file for some reason. I am going to try and figure out whats happening. Thanks a million.